# Controller is not defined in AngularJS 1.3.7

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do routing in angular Js in mvc but I am not able to find solution for this errors.

1. $injector:modulerr this Error i am getting
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined

   ```
   <html lang="en" ng-app="APP">
   <head><script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       var app = angular.module('APP', ['ngResource']).
        config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            When('/', { templateUrl: '/Project/Template/RouteTemplate.html', controller: 'directoryController'}),
            When('/view', { templateUrl: '/Project/Template/Home.html' })
        });

       controller('directoryController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $htp) {

           alert("hai");
       }])
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="">
       <div ng-controller="directoryController">
           <div ng-view>

           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `app.controller` and it is `$http` not `$htp`

```
 controller('directoryController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $htp) {
```

should be:

```
 app.controller('directoryController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not chaining, after the end of `.config` remove the `;` and add another `.` to chain the `controller` call:

```
angular.module('APP', ['ngResource']).config({}).controller()
                                                ^^ MISSING THIS
```